# C# Library for converting Shapefile Projection

Tags: projection, shapefile

Is there any C# library which can take a shapefile as an input with projection information defined (e.g, EPSG 3011) and return a new shapefile with user specified projection (e.g, EPSG 4326) ?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to projections, the de-facto standard is PROJ4. A simple google search of "proj4 c# wrapper" resulted in some promising results, like this one:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/C-NET-wrapper-updated-td3841800.html

library lives in http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/

I haven't personally tested though.